# Saving image taken from camera without compression

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I am using this method to save an image taken from the camera to the internal storage:

```
public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile( getActivity(),
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

The storaged image size is about 15.24 kB, but the same image taken from the camera without using my app has a size of 3.59MB.
I need to storage the image from my app without compressing or with a smaller compression.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

I guess the issue is due to this part of onActiciyResult:

```
if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");




            selectedFilePath = saveImage(bitmap);





            fotoActual.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            nombreArchivo.setText( selectedFilePath);
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"","Subiendo foto ...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                    uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

Using `Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` returns the Thumbnail not the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the URI from a file when you're starting the camera, like this:

```
    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);

    myFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, "MyPhoto.jpeg");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(myFile)); --> you have to do this

    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
```

Doing this, you don't need to call saveImage on Activity result.

Comment: Is there another way to get bitmap not the thumbnail? I would like not to change any other part of the code.

Comment: I'm sorry @mvasco, I don't know another way to do it